# JavaScript to change input value by specifying form and class name

Tags: javascript, html

I need a way to change the value of an input box by referring to it by form and class name. Given a form that looks like this:

```
<form name="foo">
<input type="text" class="bar" value="someval" />
</form>
```

Is there a one-line solution to this? I've tried some things such as:

```
document.foo.getElementsByClassName('bar')[0].setAttribute("value", "newvalue");
```

And

```
document.forms['foo'].getElementsByClassName('bar')[0].setAttribute("value", "newvalue");
```

To no avail. There must be something obvious I'm missing, but what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is precisely what [`.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) was designed to help with. You can pass any valid CSS selector to it and it will return the first element that matches the query or `undefined` if no match is found.

And, [don't use `.getElementsByClassName()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54952474/695364) or `document.forms` (ever) as they are both ancient techniques that either introduce major performance issues or non-modern approaches that are inferior to the APIs we have today.

```js
// Find the input element with a class of "bar" that is a direct child of a form with a name attribute of "foo"
document.querySelector("form[name='foo'] > input.bar").value = "blah"
```

```html
<form name="foo">
  <input type="text" class="bar" value="someval" />
</form>
```

Comment: I get the sense of your code but I'm still getting a null reference for some reason. Are there any "gotchas" to this approach when combined with programming MVC C#?

Comment: @Rafe You must run this code AFTER the HTML has been parsed, so put your script just before the closing BODY tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this

```
document.forms[0].querySelector(".bar").value
```

And if you have multiple forms, just loop through document.forms and get values by class name, use querySelector or select by id whatever suits you.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You're mixing the BOM and the DOM. It works, but really makes no sense.

Comment: Can you give me more clarification, like as per my understanding BOM would include access and manipulation of the browser window? I understand this is not the most elegant way the code and you answer makes more sense.

Comment: `document.forms[0]` Uses the "Browser Object Model", which is a de facto standard from the earliest days of web scripting. `.querySelector()` is part of the W3C Document Object Model standard that all modern code should utilize.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" class="bar" value="someval" />
</form>

<script>
    document.getElementsByClassName("bar")[0].value = "newvalue";
</script>
```

Comment: [No, no, no!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54952088/how-to-modify-style-to-html-elements-styled-externally-with-css-using-js/54952474#54952474)